# Find the volume of the region $S$ whose base is enclosed by the parabola $y = 2-3x^2$ and the x-axis where...

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the volume of the region $S$ whose base is enclosed by the parabola $y = 2-3x^2$ and the x-axis and where the cross sections perpendicular to the base are squares

So I've already done this question successfully when slicing horizontally, so that I have a $dy$ at the end of my integral. I was hoping somebody could show me how to do it with vertical slices so there will be a $dx$ at the end of my integral.

For the bounds of integration is solved for when $y=0$ and got $x = \pm \sqrt{2/3}$

so my integral became $$\int_{-\sqrt{2/3}}^{\sqrt{2/3}}A(x)dx = \int_{-\sqrt{2/3}}^{\sqrt{2/3}}(2-3x^2)^2dx \cong 3.4837$$

Which is not correct.. Where did I go worng here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's not wrong, it's a different problem. You need to specify in which direction your cross section is square. I can have squares with one side in the $xy$ plane, perpendicular to the $x$ axis, or to the $y$ axis, or to any axis in the horizontal plane. Try to get a value of the height of the figure at some random point, using different axes.